# browserAction.setTitle not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add a number that will show up when you mouseover the chrome extension icon, and this number will change as the script runs. However, when I add

```
 chrome.browserAction.setTitle({
    title:'it works!';
});
```

into my content.js file, the entire script stops working. My manifest.json file currently looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "sampleName",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
      "storage"
        ],
   "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "not working"
   },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.sample.com"
      ],
  "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything works perfectly when I remove the chrome.browserAction.setTitle statement from content.js, so something about that statement is breaking my entire script.

Comment: You cannot access chrome.browserAction from content script, use a background page

Comment: is using localStorage/sessionStorage the best way to transfer values between content.js and background.js?

Comment: I'd use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar issue even though I am calling `chrome.browserAction.setTitle` in the background script.

It was resolved by removing the `default_title` from `browser_action` in `manifest.json`. It works as expected since then.